# Transferring a CSV file to a database while merging some columns

Tags: python, beginner, csv, sqlite

Say I am given a csv file that I want to import into an sqlite3 database.  The first two columns in the csv file contain unique, important information while the rest of the columns are really a list of things.  So the csv file with the header row could look like:

**cucumber.csv**

> ```
> 'important1', 'important2', 'listItem_1', 'listItem_2', 'listItem_3'
> '123', '9876', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'
> '456', '7890', 'cabbage', 'onion', 'carrot'
> ```

So, when I import into the database, I want to shove all but the first two columns into one column.  The schema for the table in the database would then look like:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

def main():
    data_filename = 'cucumber.csv'
    db_filename = 'spam_mart.sqlite'
    SQL_create_table = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cucumber;
                          CREATE TABLE cucumber (
                          important1  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                          important2  NUMBER,
                          item_list   TEXT
                       );
                       """
    SQL = """insert into cucumber(important1, important2, item_list)
             values (:important1, :important2, :item_list)
          """

    with open(data_filename) as f, sqlite3.connect(db_filename) as conn:
        conn.executescript(SQL_create_table)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        reader_object = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader_object, None)      # Skip the headers
        row_count = 0
        for row in reader_object:
            row_count += 1
            row_dict = {}
            important1, important2, *item_list = row  # unpack the row
            row_dict['important1'] = important1
            row_dict['important2'] = important2
            row_dict['item_list'] = repr(item_list)  # convert list to string first
            cursor.execute(SQL, row_dict)

    print('Loaded {} of {} records'.format(str(row_count),
                                       str(reader_object.line_num - 1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I would normally use a `csv.DictReader()` object to transfer a csv file to a database, but since I was creating a list from some of the columns first, I am going with a normal `csv.reader()` object.

I used the `repr()` so that I can easily access the list again using the `eval()` if need be.  Script works as expected.  However, the whole technique seems a little clumsy to me.  All honest critiques welcomed.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to store a serialized blob in a database?

Comment: Thanks @200_success.  Your _Why_ question is very valid and one I am putting some serious thought to.  The answer last night was "hey, those things are a list, let's keep them as a list", but not sure that's good enough for me this morning.  Anyway, I will post my revised thoughts.  In the meantime, could I toss the question back to you and ask ***Why not?***  As a [tag:beginner], I would really appreciate your thoughts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`csv.DictReader` accepts 'restKey' 3rd parameter.

```
with open(data_filename) as f, sqlite3.connect(db_filename) as conn:
        conn.executescript(SQL_create_table)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        next(f, None)      # Skip the headers
        reader_object = csv.DictReader(f,['important1','important2'],'item_list')
        row_count = 0
        for row_dict in reader_object:
            row_count += 1
            row_dict['item_list'] = repr(row_dict['item_list'])  # convert list to string first
            cursor.execute(SQL, row_dict)
```

Comment: Using this approach, one would need to remove the `next(f, None)` statement, correct?

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: nevermind... just being a `bonehead`.  I was going to say "because you skipped the headers", ignoring the fact that you defined them explicitly.  Gonna play with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to do the counting:

```
for row_count, row in enumerate(reader_object, 1):
```

Your printing:

```
print('Loaded {} of {} records'.format(str(row_count),
                                   str(reader_object.line_num - 1)))
```

does not need the calls to `str`. Just do

```
print('Loaded {} of {} records'.format(row_count, reader_object.line_num - 1))
```

or, even,

```
print('Loaded', row_count, 'of', reader_object.line_num - 1, 'records')
```

Personally the indentation of the strings is odd; I'd treat it more like a block of code and indent it singly. This is more my preference than anything.

According to PEP 8, the name `SQL` should be lowercase. Similarly with the name `f`, which should be longer. However, these are hardly big deals.